# Force YouTube videos to play HD inside Fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, youtube, fancybox

I've got Fancybox set for opening YouTube videos in a popup and I finally got it to work with the iPad and the iPhone. Now, is there any possibility to force YouTube to play the video in the highest definition inside the popup despite the width and height of the popup window? I've already set the hd=1 in the video link but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancyYouTube").click(function() {
            $.fancybox({
                'type' : 'iframe',
                'padding' : 0,
                'autoscale' : false,
                'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                'title' : '',
                'width' : 853,
                'height' : 480,
                'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp('youtu.be', 'i'), 'www.youtube.com/embed').replace(new RegExp('watch\\?v=', 'i'), 'embed/'),
                });
                return false;
        });
    });

</script>


<a class="fancyYouTube" href="http://youtu.be/vn9bofoCYmE?hd=1"><img src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/7-z939fbbvw/mqdefault.jpg"/></a>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily just append: &autoplay=1&hd=1 to the video url.

Comment: You have to wait until the advertisement is over. Otherwise it seems like its not playing in HD.